# Jobs portal is not working when clicking on detail jobs view

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On the [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/) portal we are able to see the company page, https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/atlassian.com.

When clicking on the detail page, it gives an error:

https://talent.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=%2Fso-proxy%2Fjobs%2F131082%2Fprincipal-platform-developer-atlassian%3Fa%3D5uN0wANYQLtZCY9y

Comment: Looks like it just got fixed? I had a repro a couple of minutes ago but now it works for me. YMMV.

Comment: @rene yes it seems fixed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry - we had to take one of the Elastic Search servers offline to replace a faulty DIMM.

It *shouldn't* have affected any search queries, but Elastic Search being what it is, and that particular cluster being very heavily utilised, there was a brief blip in availability as Elastic shards re-balanced.